# Spring boot, Hibernate JPA MySQL 5.7 Incorrect string value: '\xE8....' for column

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, character-encoding

I am getting Incorrect string value: '\xE8.....' for column ...

I have set char encoding to utf8mb4 on Database (MySQL 5.7.23) and jdbc url i have appended  ?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false

Still I am getting error from Hibernate

2022-04-13 00:34:35.083  WARN 8 --- [ad Pool Data -7] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
2022-04-13 00:34:35.083 ERROR 8 --- [ad Pool Data -7] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : Incorrect string value: '\xE8....' for column '....' at row 1

What I am missing here.

Comment: Thanks for all the support.

Found myself the root cause. It wasn't the issue with the table or with the jdbc connection. Issue was in the custom function. My query had a custom function where I haven't mentioned returned type as utf8mb4, it was taken default charset. when i changed the return type to use utf8mb4 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You were expecting a grave-e (`è`)?  The configuration you present disagrees with the *encoding* of the source.  `E8` is probably `latin1` or `cp1256`, not `UTF-8`.

Either fix the source data be hex `C3E8` so that it agrees with `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` or change that setting.